# Global tide calculation

Tags: oceanography, tides, ocean-models

I am familiar with the concept of harmonic tide coefficients and was wondering about the simplest software solution to calculate tides anywhere, worldwide.

Are there any available, open source packages to achieve this?

Thanks,
EL

Answer (score 2):

Science-quality tools for global and regional tidal heights and transports are available at 
http://volkov.oce.orst.edu/tides/global.html.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking for production quality tools. OTIS documentation is so sparse that you need a PhD to install - at least that was my experience few years ago. Any alternatives / user friendlier packages you know? But I'll look into the TPXO9-atlas more carefully. What do the abbreviations : "M2 S2 N2 K2 ... " stand for? The regions on the map?

Comment: Might be good additional standalone questions, as others may have the same struggles, and maybe John or others can solve them!

Comment: The abbreviations are the tide constituents, not the regions.

Comment: The Tidal Model Driver (https://www.esr.org/research/polar-tide-models/tmd-software/) works in Matlab (not open source), but it needed some minor editing: (i) replacing break statements with errors and (ii) updating a command to add a path. Additional steps were to (i) download the TPXO binaries, (ii) unzip/untar them, and (iii) update the paths in the control file to point to the unpacked binaries. I was able to plot a 60 day times series of tidal SSH in the eastern Pacific Ocean.